# IE10 Video Tag suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video, tags

Iv'e got no idea why, but ie10 stopped loading a video tag on a website i'm working on.

Here's the code i've implemented:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="width: auto;height: 100%;">

<source src="video/background.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />
<source src="video/background.ogv"  type="video/ogg"  />
<source src="video/background.webm" type="video/webm" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<object id="video_background_1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
<param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashVars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=over&amp;file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloodandtreasure.com%2FGSC%2Fvideo%2Fbackground.mp4&amp;repeat=always" />
</object>

<![endif]-->

</video>
```

[Here's](http://www.bloodandtreasure.com/GSC/) the link to the website. The video works perfectly fine in windows media player with a .mp4 extension.

I really have no idea what the problem is, so if anyone has run into this problem before please let me know what worked for you.

Best Regards,

Oscar

P.S: I'm going to bed now and will check any updates to this question in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting your website I'm not seeing any issue that is specific to the video element mentioned in your question. I'm able to verify that the video loads and plays in IE10, Chrome 28, and Firefox 23. However, I am seeing a warning showing up in all browsers:

```
<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/bloodand/public_html/GSC/header.php:1) in <b>/home/bloodand/public_html/GSC/db.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
```

In IE10 this is also outputting additional errors in the console. I believe this is due to the fact that the above warning is being entered into the html outside of the `<html>` tag.

HTML1513: Extra "`<html>`" tag found. Only one "`<html>`" tag should exist per document. 
GSC, line 4 character 1

HTML1503: Unexpected start tag. 
GSC, line 6 character 1

HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
GSC, line 34 character 1

HTML1514: Extra "`<body>`" tag found. Only one "`<body>`" tag should exist per document. 
GSC, line 36 character 1

I would suggest looking into what is modifying your headers. This may fix any issues that you're seeing. Also, be aware that you have a repeating Javascript error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined header.js 317

Comment: Yes that seems to have sorted it out nicely. Thank you very much for taking the time to go through the website and finding the source of the problem. Have a +1 from me. Cheers! Oscar

Comment: Thanks also for letting me know about the recurring error, i'll fix that now.